# How to find the element in an string array if its content contains my search term

Tags: c#, arrays, search, contains

My string array is like this:

```
string[] headers = {"Row Nr", "StartDate", "StartTime", "Q_1", "Q_96"};
```

How can I find the element in the array, which contains my search term "date"?

I know how to find an element that it's value is equal to my search term, like this:

```
var match = headers.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains("StartDate"));
```

But I didn't find any solution that finds me an element when part of my element with IgnoreCase contains the search item, i.e., searching "date" instead of "StartDate" in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This overload **Contains(String value, StringComparison comparisonType)** is not included in netstandard2.0.

Here is a an alternative:

```
        string[] headers = { "Row Nr", "StartDate", "StartTime", "Q_1", "Q_96" };
        var match = headers.FirstOrDefault(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) && c.IndexOf("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use another overload for `Contains` method:

```
var match = headers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Contains("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitry. But in this case as you suggested I get an error as follows: No overload for method 'Contains' takes two argument!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem as follows:

```
private void setDateColumnTitle ()
{
string stringToCheck = "date";
int stringToCheckIndex = -1;
string elementInArray = "Not Defined or Not Found";
if (Array.Exists<string> (headers, (Predicate<string>) delegate (string s)
    {
        stringToCheckIndex = s.IndexOf (stringToCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        elementInArray = s;
        return stringToCheckIndex > -1;
        }))
    {
    dateColTitle.Text = elementInArray; //a textbox to show the output
    }
}
```

However, I found @Lev answer simpler and shorter giving the same result as follows:

```
    private void setDateColumnTitle ()
{

dateColTitle.Text = "Not Defined or Not Found";

var match = headers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IndexOf("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);

if (match!=null)                
    dateColTitle.Text = match;               
}
```

So, it deserved to be chosen as an answer to this problem.

Comment: Thank you, please note that I updated my original answer with 2 fixes:
added a check for IsNullOrEmpty, and change the condition to check for index to be greater than or equal to 0, for cases when the string starts with "date"

Comment: Thanks for improving the code. By the way, I think this part (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ) is not needed. Whether the array element is a string that does'n match or it's null, the method returns null. Only if there exist a search term within the element string, match variable finds its identity as a string!